# Is it possible to mark a PPA as "do not upgrade"?

Tags: package-management, upgrade

I needed a feature in the latest version of a program (kicad) so I added the "live" PPA and successfully downloaded & upgraded. But I don't need the very latest all the time, and the upgrades are frequent and huge and take a long time to download on my rural broadband. Hence my question - I would like to keep the program and maybe upgrade occasionally, but not every time, I'm happy with what I've got for the time being.

Comment: You put the package. Not the repositories, on hold or remove the repo from your sources

Comment: The other option, aside from holding the package, is to simply disable the PPA. The package will remain, it just won't see any updates.

Comment: It may be upgraded if the package is in other repos, I go best put the package(s) on hold

Comment: Thank you all, I did not know about package holding but that is just what I was after.